# how can i save treeviewitem when right mouse is clicked on it and context manu is open?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, treeviewitem

I'm using wpf(C#)
I want to right click on tree view Item and then a context manu will pop up with menu items that will do actions on the selected/right clicked tree view item with the context manu items
tried to use
`tree_view_item.MouseRightButtonUp += Item_MouseRightButtonUp;`
but then i couldnt use the the items in the context manu of the path of the tree view item

Answer (score 0):

Every `FrameworkElement` has a [`ContextMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contextmenu?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.8)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8#examples) property. Just add `MenuItem` elements to it:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="TreeViewItemContextMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="OnSaveItemClicked"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </Window.Resources>

  <TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>      
      <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value"{StaticResource TreeViewItemContextMenu}" /> 
      </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>  
  </TreeView>
<Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow
{
  private void OnSaveItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var item = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext; // TODO: Cast to data type
    Save(item);
  }
}
```